# Angular HTTP request and get result to promise to init service

Tags: angular

The examples at https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt6#tap-into-the-observable don't work.

This used to work but something in Angular must have changed and now it doesn't work any more and I don't understand what to do to make it work -- is this still the right way of doing it or has it changed?

```
  init(): Promise<Settings> {
    return this.http.get<Settings>('settings').pipe(
      tap(response => this.settings = response)
    ).toPromise<Settings>();
  }
```

```
error TS2322: Type 'Promise<Settings | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Settings>'.
  Type 'Settings | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Settings'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Settings'.
```

Answer (score 1):

`toPromise` was deprecated in RxJS 7 which introduced the breaking change you are experiencing: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

> ..the return type of the Observable's toPromise() method has been fixed to better reflect the fact that Observables can yield zero values. This may be a breaking change to some projects as the return type was changed from Promise to Promise<T | undefined>.

Assuming you want to keep using promises, the recommendation is to use either:

- [`firstValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom)
- [`lastValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom)

For example:

```
import { withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

init(): Promise<Settings> {
  const getSettings$: Observable<Settings> =
    this.http.get<Settings>('settings')
      .pipe(
        tap(response => this.settings = response)
      );

  return firstValueFrom(getSettings$)
}
```

Comment: So how should this now be done?

Comment: Instead of `someObservable$.toPromise()` you would instead use `firstValueFrom(someObservable$)`. For a single emission observable you can use either `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom` to return the same promise; the difference is only relevant for observable streams that emit more than one value. I have updated my answer to show an example for your use case.

Comment: It sounded like I shouldn't be using `Promise` at all because they've been deprecated?

Comment: What is the `$` on `getSettings$`?

Comment: I don't seem to have a `firstValueFrom`; this doesn't compile.

Comment: `Promise` is still fine, however the RxJS API is much more comprehensive than the `Promise` API so its generally recommended to work with `Observable`s over `Promise`s in Angular apps, even for single value async operations like a http GET. The `$` is just a naming convention that denotes that the variable contains an observable, see https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables. `firstValueFrom` is imported from 'rxjs/operators', I have added the import statement to the example. Let me know if you still have issues!

Comment: It doesn't work if you change `Promise` to `Observable`.